# Data Services with POCO that are dynamicly Created

Tags: wcf, wcf-data-services

Try to understand what the options might be with use of WCF Data Services,  Basicly i'm trying to abstract a 3rd party http API by making a RestFull services from the 3rd Party set of api calls.  On top of this im intrested in the Odata representation and Api support that Data Services.

Example 3rd Party Call,

1)GetAll Vehicles

```
  I want to represent it in a restfull call http://localhost/Vehicles
```

2)GetVehicleLocation(vehicles)

```
  I want to represent it in a restfull call http://localhost/Vehicles(1)/Location
```

The challenge im looking at how can i invoke the List {to make it simple} from the web service call.  This part is striaght forward where i need some guidance is when were doing the Call 2),  since the Location infomation is based off a webservice call passing the Vehcle,  Linq to Object is assuming the POCO are filled if im understanding correctly..

This article
[Data Services Streaming](https://web.archive.org/web/20160214214143/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/tom_laird-mcconnell/archive/2010/01/18/using-ado-net-wcf-data-services-for-streaming-infinite-event-result-sets.aspx) seems to be on the path...

Answer (score 1):

I'm presently investigating a similar scenario. Since the primary use case for WCF Data Services is exposing your database tables through Entity framework, finding good information on doing anything else is a bit thin on the ground.

What you are trying to do is fairly straightforward in fact, and can be simplified by using the WCF Data Services Toolkit; [you want to wrap odata around what](http://lostintangent.com/post/3189655590/you-want-to-wrap-odata-around-what)

You will need to expose two entity types at the root level, Vehicle and Location

1. You need a `DataService<MyDataContext>` as the entry point of the service, this will need to define two IQueryable properties for Vehicles and Locations. You may not really need to access Locations at the root level, but its the only way to make this work with the underlying reflection provider. Without having Location at the root level the service will not expose the metadata for the Location entity.
2. Your Vehicle entity will need a Location property with a `[ForeignProperty]` attribute
3. You must implement a repository for Vehicles having methods named; `GetOne(string id)`, `GetAll()` and `GetLocationByVehicle(string id)` method, the id will be the VehicleId that you need to make your api call.

making a Get request on /Vehicles will invoke the GetAll() method on the repository, /Vehicles(1) will invoke the GetOne() method and /Vehicles(1)/Location will invoke the GetLocationByVehicle() method passing in the Id '1'.